# how to batch merge multiple imported functions that come from the same file or module in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any tools can do it? how to do it? thank you!

```js
// original codes.
import { fnA, fnB } from './moduleA';
import { fnC } from './moduleA';

// after merged.
import { fnA, fnB, fnC } from './moduleA';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) Tool recommendations are *specifically* off-topic as they lead to opinion-based answers that become irrelevant after a fairly brief time.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, Yes.

You'll need an editor or code formatter with *import sorting* or *import optimizing* capabilities.

- Visual Studio Code extension (You'll have to install this extension)

  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dozerg.tsimportsorter
- Intellij IDEA/Webstorm (Built into the IDE)

  https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/05/optimize-imports-in-webstorm/
- Prettier Plugin (If you're using prettier in your project)

  https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier-plugin-organize-imports